# We applied for the UK visit visa as a family but each member got an appointment on different days. Can we all attend at the time of one member?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

We applied for UK standard visit visa as a family. 
Each member filled a separate form and we all made payments. 
Our dad, who will be the primary in this case, made the payment first. 
The problem is that all of us got appointments at different times and even on different days. 
So my mother's is scheduled a day before my father and sister. 
The rest of us siblings have it on the 3 days later.
The most suitable date for us would be the earliest, with our mom.
Would it be possible for us to attend the appointment along with her as a family?
do you think I should make a local call to the British consulate or do they not entertain such issues on the call?
ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you applied online, you would have received an email acknowledgement, including advice on how to change your appointment online.

Comment: yup, we can change appointments. But now, early dates are not available. we would all like to go with our mom because we are traveling to another country in 20 days and would need our passports for that.

Comment: I can’t find a definitive source but I’d imagine that it’s highly unlikely that additional applicants can join another applicant’s appointment. Unless you requested the Priority Service, the published processing timeframe for non-settlement visa applications is 15 working days, as you probably already know.

Answer (score 1):

According to the major companies through which UK visa applications are filed, TSLcontact and VFSGlobal, group appointments must be requested and booked in advance, and may be a premium fee-based service. While your family has a number of appointments scheduled, appearing as a group may not succeed, unless arranged in advance.

The following are randomly-selected examples, as you don't indicate the country from which you're applying, but the option is available at any centre.

> [**TLScontact Group Appointment Service**](https://uk.tlscontact.com/eg/aly/page.php?pid=added_value_services#group%20appointment)
>
> The Visa Application Centre will arrange Group Appointment Bookings for organisations, tour operators and large families who want to apply at the same time at the Visa Application Centre but they have been unable to coordinate appointments online.
>
> This service also includes preliminary bundling of passports, saving time to the group leader when picking up ready applications.
>
> To arrange for the group appointment, please speak to one of the staff members in the Visa Application Centre or contact us via the Feedback and Complaints section.
>
> Please note:
>
> - Only people traveling together are considered a group.
> - Group appointments have to be scheduled at least 1 working day in advance, subject to availability.
> - This service does not guarantee that all applications will return on the same day as each application is treated separately.
>
> To purchase this service, please log in at your personal account on this Website and purchase it or ask our representatives at the Reception for assistance, when you arrive at the Visa Application Centre.

---

> [**VFS Global Group Appointment Booking**](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/lk/en/premium-services/group-appointment-booking)
>
> Book a group appointment on a specified day, and save time and travel costs to the visa application centre
>
> If you are travelling as a group, it can take time and repeated trips to the visa application centre before everyone has submitted all the required documentation.
>
> It can be hard to keep track of who has already visited the centre, and who is still waiting.
>
> A group appointment eases this process, allowing a group to apply for appointments together at the same visa application centre, on the same day.
>
> It’s ideal for families, tour operators, work conferences, students and anyone travelling in a group.
>
> Group appointments can be made by emailing your chosen visa application centre to arrange a date and time.